# Average of first ten numbers of text file using bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file of two columns. The first column is dates and the second contains a corresponding number. The two commas are separated by a column. I want to take the average of the first three numbers and print it to a new file. Then do the same for the 2nd-4th number. Then 3rd-5th and so on. For example:

File1

```
date1,1  
date2,1  
date3,4  
date4,1  
date5,7
```

Output file

```
2  
2  
4
```

Is there any way to do this using awk or some other tool?

Comment: definitely. poke around in the archives to find it. it shouldn't take long.

Comment: You may also want to google "moving average"

Comment: @James, you are expected to have put some effort into your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the format of the date?

Comment: @glenn. sorry I am brand new to using this kind of system and had no idea where to start. It did help tremendously knowing there was a name for this though so thank you

Answer (score 0):

*updated based on the changes made due to the helpful feedback from Ed Morton*

here's a quick and dirty script to do what you've asked for. It doesn't have much flexibility in it but you can easily figure out how to extend it. 
To run save it into a file and execute it as an awk script either with a shebang line or by calling *awk* -f

```
// {
  Numbers[NR]=$2;
  if ( NR  >= 3 ) {
    printf("%i\n", (Numbers[NR] + Numbers[NR-1] + Numbers[NR-2])/3)
  }
}

BEGIN {
  FS=","
}
```

Explanation:

Line 1: Match all lines, "/" is the match operator and in this case we have an empty match which means "do this thing on every line".

---

Line 3: Use the Record Number (NR) as the key and store the value from column 2

---

Line 4: If we have 3 or more values read from the file

---

Line 5: Do the maths and print as an integer

---

BEGIN block: Change the Field Separator to a comma ",".

---

Comment: `//` does nothing and you're setting `FS` **after** the first line has been read. Set it in a BEGIN section.

Comment: I don't agree that // "does nothing". Yes the code will work without it but it does actually do something.

You're absolutely right about the FS. In my haste that one slipped past me. thanks for pointing it out.. editing my post now...

much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat file.txt 
date1,1
date2,1
date3,4
date4,1
date5,7 

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -v n=3 -v FS=, '{
    x = $2;
    i = NR % n;
    ma += (x - q[i]) / n;
    q[i] = x;
    if(NR>=n)print ma;
}' file.txt
2
2
4
```

**OR below one useful for plotting and keeping reference axis (in your case date) at center of average point**

**Script**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat avg.awk 
BEGIN {
    m=int((n+1)/2)
}
{L[NR]=$2; sum+=$2}
NR>=m {d[++i]=$1}
NR>n {sum-=L[NR-n]}
NR>=n{
    a[++k]=sum/n
}
END {
    for (j=1; j<=k; j++)
        print d[j],a[j]          # remove d[j], if you just want values only
}
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk -v n=3 -v FS=, -v OFS=, -f avg.awk file.txt 
date2,2
date3,2
date4,4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, '{a[NR%3]=$2} (NR>=3){print (a[0]+a[1]+a[2])/3}' file
2
2
4
```

Add a little bit math tricks here, set `$2` to `a[NR%3]` for each record. So the value in each element would be updated cyclically. And the sum of a[0], a[1], a[2] would be the sum of past 3 numbers.